# WooCommerce to Magento migration

Tags: migration, woocommerce

We're trying for the first time to manually do a migration from WooCommerce to Magento because we want to understand the nuts and bolts of everything that "should" happen in this process because no doubt, if we do this for another client, say with Microsoft product items, we will know what to do.

I have started a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKSUXPttdu4bXUC5SidhBA29vDayW54HkX4yEIlmF6A/edit?usp=sharing) that matches the column names in WooCommerce with the column names in Magento. The idea is then to create a script that you could potentially import your two spreadsheets and easily rename the correct columns.

Does something like this already exist...not software that has been.

Many thanks.

Comment: why do you need to migrate? from my experience WP+WC very fast and easy manageable platform.

Comment: No there isn't a freeware that does this for you as far as I know. You typically have to do these things yourself and make it your know-how, or hire somebody else that does it professionally.

Comment: @ADM We're offering both solutions. People who need to migrate from WooCommerce to Magento because it offers a lot more.

Comment: Thanks @musicliftsme, we're finding that too! We have someone with pro experience we will next be calling on to help us with this

Answer (score 1):

The idea looks good but I haven't come across a readymade script like that. Performing migration manually will be safe and error free as the one mentioned here http://blog.contus.com/migrate-from-woocommerce-to-a-magento-platform.